# RGB color incorrect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicolor

I have a very simple method that sets an r,g, and b color. It is the following:

```
-(void)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue{
    r = red;
    g = green;
    b = blue;

    NSLog(@"R: %f, G: %f, B: %f",r,g,b);
}
```

r,g,b, and o (opacity) are float properties in my custom subclass of uiview. I utilize draw rect like the following:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, b, g, o);
```

When I call the method I do it like this:

```
[self.drawingBox colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0];
NSLOG: R: 1.000000, G: 0.231373, B: 0.188235
```

This works correctly and returns a red color with which I draw.

Unfortunately, whenever I call anything else, it doesn't return the desired color even though it's nslogging the correct color. For example,

```
[self.drawingBox colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:149.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0];
```

Returns a purple color when it should actually be orange. When it gets nslogged, this is what logs for the orange color:

```
R: 1.000000, G: 0.584314, B: 0.000000
```

Any ideas on why the second time it returns purple instead of orange (the nslog is the correct color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameters to `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` in the wrong order. Try this:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, o);
```

Comment: I feel so foolish. I just typed too fast!! Thanks, will accept when the time limit is up!